# Heart ❤ symbol is missing on some Android devices

Tags: android, unicode, symbols

I am using ❤ symbol in my [android widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.artemzin.android.love), but on some Android 2.x devices and on Android 2.x emulators I got a square symbol like this □ instead of ❤

What you would recommend to me? I`m thinking about using custom font with that symbol...

May be some companies just removing not necessary symbols from system fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fonts shipped with Android don’t seem to contain the heart symbol; even the [Droid Sans Pro](http://www.droidfonts.com/info/droid-sans-fonts/) fonts, available for extra fee, don’t have it.

If you only need one special character not covered by common fonts, it is probably best to use an image for it. Create an image with the symbol in large size (say, 5 or 10 times common text font size), and use an scales it down to copy text size.

There are free fonts that contain the “❤” character, but it sounds pointless to use a font (typically, a large font, which needs to be served in different font formats) just to get one symbol displayed.

Comment: That`s strange, because on both of devises (Android 2.x) of my friends ❤ symbol is rendering normally, and all of Android 4.x devices and emulators got that symbol.

Comment: ❤ image solution is not good for me, because I need text scaling and text shadows.. It will be hard to create shadow for image, that will be same as text shadow :( May be I could use Android 4.x fonts

Answer (score 6):

Well I'd just load a Custom font or maybe even a newer version of the default android font used in later devices... Or you might even get away with displaying a picture depending on what your doing, and what your goals are...